# How do you "debug" a graphics card without a screen?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I'm trying to see if a graphics card I inherited from a friend is in working order. I've removed my card from my computer and installed (physically) the new card. All of the cables look to be in their place, I can turn on my PC, and I can see that the fan is running. However, my monitor (which is plugged in, i double checked) shows nothing. It has the yellow light, indicating it is idle and receiving no video feed. My motherboard has no HDMI, VGA, etc port to speak of. My mouse lights up, and i suspected that I was at a bios screen that indicated it did not shut down correctly (because it didn't). So I hit enter, watched my mouse flicker and then turn back on. So I can guess that my computer is functioning, but I'm not sure how to debug the problem.

So how can I debug the problem if I can't see anything?

Running Windows 7. The card appears to be a [HIS IceQ X Radeon HD 7850](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161405)

Comment: How many PCIe 16X slots is there in your computer?

Comment: If you think it's working well enough to boot into Windows, you could always connect via Remote Desktop and continue troubleshooting that way, though keep in mind there are some aspects of monitor configuration you cannot manipulate via an RDP session.

Comment: @AliChen I believe there are two, but I'll have to double check. I'm not at home right now.

Answer (score 1):

First, try to plug your monitor into each of four output ports of the Radeon card. It is possible that only certain output gets configured on power-on default.

If no luck, get another older PC with regular PCI slot (and a PCIe slot for the questionable Radeon card). And get a very basic (but known good) PCI video card. Or, if you have a PC with two x16 PCIe slots, get a working PCIe video card.

Start first with good video card, and get all necessary drivers. Direct BIOS to configure the card as primary video, if possible. Then turn power off, and plug the questionable card, and work from there. If the Radeon is half functional, you should see something in device manager.